# Values of one file to change corresponding value in another file?

Tags: awk, sed

I need help with a simple dash script solution. A script reading the values of file: "Install.txt", (sample content):

```
TRUE 203
TRUE 301
TRUE 602
TRUE 603
```

The numbers will correspond with the same number (at the end of line) in file: "ExtraExt.sys", (sample content):

```
# Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/diaryThumbPlace #202
# Read $[CORE_DIR]/myBorderStyle #203
# Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/mMenu #301
# Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/dDecor #501
# Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/controlPg #601
# Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/DashToDock #602
# Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/deskSwitch #603
```

All lines are tagged (#). The script will untag the corresponding line that has the same number as in the file "install.txt". For example, **TRUE 203** will untag the line ending with **#203**

```
# Read $[CORE_DIR]/myBorderStyle #203
```

to (without "#" before Read)

```
Read $[CORE_DIR]/myBorderStyle #203
```

I've searched for awk/sed solution, but this requires a loop to go through the numbers in Install.txt.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try,

```
# store "203|301|602|603" in search variable
search=$(awk 'BEGIN{OFS=ORS=""}{if(NR>1){print "|"}print $2;}' Install.txt)
sed -r "s/^# (.*#($search))$/\1/g" ExtraExt.sys
```

you get,

```
# Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/diaryThumbPlace #202
Read $[CORE_DIR]/myBorderStyle #203
Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/mMenu #301
# Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/dDecor #501
# Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/controlPg #601
Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/DashToDock #602
Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/deskSwitch #603
```

or, -i option for edit in file

```
sed -i -r "s/^# (.*#($search))$/\1/g" ExtraExt.sys
```

Answer (score 0):

One option using awk could be reading the first file *Install.txt* and store the values of the second field in `arr`

Reading the second file *ExtraExt.sys* you could get numbers of the last column using `$NF` and match that against the pattern `^#[0-9]+$`

If there is a match, remove the `#` part from the match leaving only the number and check if the number is in `arr`.

If it is, print the current line without the leading `#`

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$2]
  next
}

match ($NF, /^#[0-9]+$/) {
  if (substr($NF, RSTART+1, RLENGTH) in arr) {
    sub(/^#[[:space:]]+/, "", $0); print $0
  }
}
' Install.txt ExtraExt.sys
```

Output

```
Read $[CORE_DIR]/myBorderStyle #203
Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/mMenu #301
Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/DashToDock #602
Read $[EXTRA_DIR]/deskSwitch #603
```